# java Перегрузка методов и generic

Tags: java, generics, function-overloading

У меня есть следующий код:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exmp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        Gen gen = new Gen();
        gen.m(integerList);
    }

    static class Gen<T>{

        <T> void m(Collection<T> collection){
            for (T s: collection) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

        void m(List<String> list){
            for (String s: list) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Никак не могу понять почему вызывается метод со списком строк. Может кто ткнет носом?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521974/why-does-the-java-8-generic-type-inference-pick-this-overload/30526908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это поведение действительно является наследием до-дженериковой эры и относится к т.н. raw type:

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible
> to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or
> the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a
> parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.
>
> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type
>   declaration without an accompanying type argument list.
> - An array type whose element type is a raw type.
> - A non-static member type of a raw type R that is not inherited from a
>   superclass or superinterface of R.
>
> [JLS 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

Raw type - это дженерик, использованный без указания типов; в данном случае raw type - это `Gen<T>`, который вы создаете как просто `Gen`. Т.к. вы не указываете тип, компилятор обрабатывает этот класс по-другому, "сбрасывая" всю generic-информацию, которую может найти:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.
>
> [JLS 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

В том числе сбрасывается информация о `List<String>` и `Collection<T>`, методы теперь выглядят как просто `m(List)` и `m(Collection)`. При выборе из этих двух методов компилятор выберет более подходящий - `m(List)`, и получится ровно та ситуация, которую мы наблюдаем. Чтобы избежать этого, достаточно вывести `Gen` из-под понятия "raw type" - это можно сделать, либо указав произвольный тип (хватит даже `Gen<?>`), либо вообще его убрав - у вас и так параметризованный метод, поэтому параметр класса в принципе не нужен.